# Find area of plane region bounded by 2 curves

Tags: calculus, area

curves: y=x+3, x=-y^2+3

My Attempt: $\int_0^{1.7320508} (-y^2+3)-(y-3) dy$ + $\int_{-1.732051}^{0} (-y^2+3)-(y-3) dy$ = 17.320

My teacher's answer is 125/6. What's my error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

You made a mistake when you computed the bounds; functions $x=y-3$ and $x=-y^2+3$ intersect at $y=-3$ and $y=+2$ and, over this range, the second curve is above the first. Then $$\int\Big((-y^2+3)-(y-3)\Big) dy=-\frac{y^3}{3}-\frac{y^2}{2}+6 y$$ and so $$\int_{-3}^{2}\Big((-y^2+3)-(y-3)\Big) dy=\frac{125}{6}$$ 
 have not been able to identify where your $\pm \sqrt 3$ come from.

Answer (score 0):

$y=x+3 \Rightarrow x=y-3$. Now consider $-y^2+3=y-3$ to see where the curves intersect:

$$y^2+y-6=0\Rightarrow y=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1-4(-6)}}{2}=\frac{-1\pm5}{2}$$
Then the intersection occurs at $y_1=-3$ and $y_2=2$. In this interval we see that $-y^2+3>y-3$, therefore the integral is:

$$\int\limits^{2}_{-3}-y^2+3-y+3 \,dy = \left[-\frac{y^3}{3}-\frac{y^2}{2}+6y\right]^2_{-3}=-\frac{8}{3}-2+12-\frac{27}{3}+\frac{9}{2}+18 = \frac{125}{6}.$$